# Iterate over the output of a command in bash without a subshell

Tags: bash, scripting, io-redirection

I want to loop over the output of a command without creating a sub-shell or using a temporary file.

The initial version of of my script looked like this, but this doesn't work since it creates a subshell, and the `exit` command terminates the subshell instead of the main script which is required.  It is part of a much larger script to configure policy routing, and it is halt the execution if it detects a condition that will cause routing to fail.

```
sysctl -a 2>/dev/null | grep '\.rp_filter' | while read -r -a RPSTAT ; do

  if [[ "0" != "${RPSTAT[2]}" ]] ; then
    echo >&2 "RP Filter must be disabled on all interfaces!"
    echo >&2 "The RP filter feature is incompatible with policy routing"
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

So one of the suggested alternatives is to use a command like this to avoid the subshell.

```
while read BLAH ; do echo $BLAH; done </root/regularfile
```

So it seems to me that I should also be able use a command like this to avoid the subshell and still get the output from the program I want.

```
while read BLAH ; do echo $BLAH; done <(sysctl -a 2>/dev/null | grep '\.rp_filter')
```

Unfortunately, using that command results in this error.

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<(sysct ...
```

I get really confused since this does work.

```
cat <(sysctl -a 2>/dev/null | grep '\.rp_filter')
```

I could save the output of that command to a temporary file, and use redirect the on the temporary file, but I wanted to avoid doing that.

So why is the redirection giving me an error, and do I have any options other then creating a temporary file?

Comment: http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Piped_%60while-read'_loop_starts_subshell http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You missed a `<`. Should be:

```
while read BLAH ; do echo $BLAH; done < <(sysctl -a 2>/dev/null | grep '\.rp_filter')
```

Think of `<(sysctl -a 2>/dev/null | grep '\.rp_filter')` being a file.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Just for my edification, can point me at a man page, help, or web page, that documents this?  I couldn't get Google to point me at anything useful while trying to search for this.

Comment: Google "process substitution". e.g. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#PROCESS-SUB

Comment: It should be noted that the <() substitution uses file descriptors and on some operating systems will transparently create & use temporary files.

Comment: @Zoredache: Simply search for `<(` in the bash manual (it's under “process substitution”).

Comment: @ewindisch, if a tool transparently creates a tempfile that is fine, I just didn't want to manually create one, when I was pretty sure I didn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

For a few more alternatives if anyone comes here again...

Depending on the shell, you could probably use `set -o errexit` to have the parent shell exit when a command (including a subshell) exits non-zero without being trapped in an `if` block or a trailing `&&` or `||`, as in

```
/bin/false || echo "ignoring error"
```

Or, you could have the subshell signal the parent using kill and the $PPID environment variable, if available.

Or you could move the while block into a function and return 0/1 (explicitly return 0 after the while block) and just do your pipeline like `sysctl | grep | function || exit`.  I suppose you could put the returns in the inline block, too, but functions are your friend. ;)